# Hide block in if condition

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm a beginner

I want to make a condition under which we either hide the block or leave it, I did it and everything works

```
@if($postsCount < 2)
    <div class="nav" style="display: none"></div>
@else
    <div class="nav"></div>
@endif
```

But I am planning to add a few more blocks and everything will look like this, there will be a lot of code copying

```
@if($postsCount < 2)
    <div class="nav" style="display: none"></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test3"></div>
    <div class="test4"></div>
@else
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test3"></div>
    <div class="test4"></div>
@endif
```

Can I do it somehow shorter so as not to copy the code again?
development environment laravel

Comment: Just put the part that is the same after the `@endif`???

Comment: Even better, why even put the nav there if you're just gonna hide it? `@if($postsCount > 1) <div class="nav"></div> @endif`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so this nav will not exist at all, but I just need to hide it

Comment: this nav should remain, it just doesn't need to be displayed if there is only 1 post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do it is to inline it using a ternary/echo. This will give you an empty style if the post count is greater than or equal to 2, or add the `display:none` if it's less.

```
<div class="nav" style="{{ $postsCount < 2 ? 'display: none' : ''}}"></div>
```

Comment: this is what I needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable

```
@php
    $css_hide="";
@endphp 

@if($postsCount < 2)
    $css_hide = 'style="display: none"';

@endif
<div class="nav" {$css_hide} ></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test3"></div>
    <div class="test4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, from the options it is to take this code into a separate file

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div class="test4"></div>
```

And on the page use like this

```
@if($postsCount < 2)
  <div style="display: none">
    @include('components.nav')
  </div>
@else
    @include('components.nav')
@endif
```

But I'm ready to look at other suggestions